# What is to be done when some user suggests edits that are necessary but isn't what OP provided info for?

Tags: support, editing, suggested-edits

So I believe I did a mistake today. There were four suggested edits pending when I came in here today. So naturally I thought of looking into them.

[This](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/267890/what-s-the-difference-between-cinema-and-theatre) was the very first question that came in. The questioner had written only three sentences asking about the difference between the two words and saying that they had searched the dictionary and found nothing useful. The editor had provided sufficient information surrounding the topic, because they might have thought someone may vote to close the question because of very less context provided by the questioner.

Now I thought the editor might have copy pasted some of the comments provided by OP later on, which sadly, was not the case. There are no comments whatsoever. I believe the editor put in all those information they deemed fit for this post which they were facing an issue with. Because I saw they have commented on rjpond's answer.

StephenS has now edited to improve the formatting, however they might have not noticed that the edit I approved was wrong.

Hence my question, **should we approve such edits which provide relevant information, but which are in no way provided or asked to be added by the questioner themselves?**

And I ask fellow moderators to please rollback the edit to the original one and do necessary formatting changes, in case such edits are not recommended. Because I believe this was a heavy change.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me going through the edit history that the edit was adding material which had not been in the OP's original question and which may or may not have conformed with what they intended. On other sites where I have the required privilege to review Suggested Edits I think I would have rejected it as not conforming to the OP's original intention or even as an attempt to answer the question in the edit.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to add in the question what the OP said in a comment, though. Rather than _adding material which had not been in the OP's original question_, I would say _adding something the OP hadn't said in the original question or in comments for that question_.

Comment: @kiamlaluno yes indeed. Funnily enough I have just approved an edit on another site (Travel) where exactly that happened, the OP clarified the countries involved but only in comments and some kind soul proposed an edit to fix the question.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the user who suggested the edit incorporated his [own](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/267890/what-s-the-difference-between-cinema-and-theatre#comment500452_267908) [comments](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/116514/%E6%88%91%E7%9A%84%E4%B8%8D%E5%A5%BD) posted on the answer into the question.

> Initially, I thought the words cinema and theatre had same meanings but I looked up multiple websites but they gave different meanings. Are they interchangeable? When can these two words be used?
>
> Here is what I personally think:
>
> - “cinema” is used to watch movies, so you see the actors through a camera
> - “theatre” is where you watch plays (e.g.Romeo and Juliet), so you see the actors on the stage.
>
> Am I correct?

That is not what the OP asked.

> Initially, I thought the cinema and theatre was the same thing but I looked up multiple websites but gave different answers. I hope all of you can provide me with the correct differences.

From the last revision, it seems the OP has an idea on what those words mean, while, from the first revision, I would take the OP doesn't have any clue on what those words mean, or when to use a word instead of the other one.

As those comments weren't posted by the OP, the suggested edit should have been rejected, since it changes the question meaning, even in the case the question has been made more acceptable.

Comment: As side note, the question passed from not containing any explicit question to having three different questions, even if they are related.